# Kylo UI - Create new typescript module

Tags: angularjs, angular, user-interface, module, kylo

I have a doubt about the way to work with Kylo and UI structure.

According to the site http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.3/developer-guides/KyloDeveloperGuide.html?highlight=angular2 it says:

> Most of the Kylo UI depends on AngularJS and AngularJS Material but a few parts have been upgraded to Angular 2 and Covalent. **New plugins should be written in Typescript and use Angular 2 for future compatibility.**

It says that new plugins should be written in angular2 and typescript, but all the examples and the core components are written in AngularJS.

One example is this one: https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/plugins/example-module/example-module-ui

I would like to know the Typescript and Angular2 alternative for that module, including routing, is there any live example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested that Angular 2 does work if the code is added directly to the kylo-ui-app project but I don't think Kylo's plugin system supports Angular 2 right now.

The only difference from standard Angular 2 is that Kylo uses UI-Router instead of the Angular Router, but the syntax is very similar. From memory I think these are the steps I used:

1) Add a new route to routes.js:

```
{
  name: 'contacts.**',
  url: '/contacts',
  loadChildren: './contacts/contacts.module#ContactsModule'
}
```

2) Add the child states to your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: CONTACTS_STATES }), /* ... and any other modules */ ],
  declarations: [ ContactComponent, /* ... and any other components */ ],
  providers: [ ContactsDataService ],
})
export class ContactsModule { }
```

3) The component for each state should be specified under views.content:

```
{
  name: 'contacts',
  url: '/contacts',
  views: {
    "content": {
      component: ContactsComponent,
    }
  }
}
```